# Error loading SQL Server data through to front end

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi I hope you can help and are having a good day :).

Essentially I am using SQL server to pull through data to my react project.
I have managed to get the data in a json form to display to localhost:5000 (where my server.js is running).I have developed a component to pull this data which could then be used within other components.

This is the code for the component (DisplayUsers).

```
import './customers.css';

class DisplayUsers extends React.Component{
  constructor(){
    super();

    this.state= { 'users':[] }
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    this.getItems();

  }

  getItems(){
fetch('/admin-view-users')
.then(recordset => recordset.json())
.then (results => this.setState({'users': results}));


  }

  render () {
    return (
    <ul>
      {this.state.users.map(function(user, index){
        return(
          <div>
          <h1>{user.name} </h1>
          <p>{user.email}</p>
          </div>
        )

        })
         }

     </ul>


    );


  }

}
export default DisplayUsers;
```

However this will throw this error

```
 Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): this.state.users.map is not a function
```

If anyone could give me some pointers on how to amend this I would be very grateful.
I am new to React but I am loving it so far :).

EDIT This is my sever.js file

````
const sql = require('mssql')
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, () => `Server running on port ${port}`);

const config = {
  user: 'sas',
  password: 'Mypassword456',
  server: 'DEVSQL_2014', // You can use 'localhost\\instance' to connect to named instance
  database: 'TestDBWebsite',
}

app.get('/admin-view-users', function (req, res) {

  // connect to your database
  sql.connect(config, function (err) {

      if (err) console.log(err);

      // create Request object
      var request = new sql.Request();

      // query to the database and get the records
      request.query('select * from Users2  ', function (err, recordset) {

          if (err) console.log(err)

         // send records as a response

          res.json(recordset)




      });
  });
}); ```
````

Comment: Please update your state declaration like this: this.state= { users: [] }

Comment: Thanks for the help but I am still receiving the same error

Comment: Please do let me know if it works

Comment: Hi Govind, It is still prompting the same issue

Comment: you're code works fine here https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-breeze-1oq70

Comment: ```TypeError: this.state.users.map is not a function```

Comment: try : {this.state.users && this.state.users.map(function(user, index){

Comment: you need to check what the value of `results`

Comment: still the same issue. Thankyou anyways though :)

Comment: How would I check the value of results ?

Comment: `.then(results => {
  console.log(results);
  this.setState({'users': results});
});`

Comment: You should update this line also: 
.then (results => this.setState({users: results}));

Comment: you're most welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think it’s necessary to do something like this:

```
...
.then (results => this.setState({'users': results.data}));
```